# Override table name when using Amazon DynamoDB DataMapper for JavaScript

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the [Amazon DynamoDB DataMapper For JavaScript](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js) to map some models to DynamoDB tables in node.js (TypeScript) lambda functions. I'm using annotations like the following:

```js
@table('Foo')
export class Foo {

    @hashKey()
    id: string;

    @attribute()
    name: string;
}
```

Does anyone know how the table name can be overridden so that a different database can be specified? For example this might be different for dev/prod environments. I couldn't see any options on DataMapper or DynamoDB config objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you define the mapper you can place a prefix dependant on environment. I use dev_ for development DB and no prefix in production:

```
const prefix = process.env.NODE_ENV != "production" ? _dev : ""     
const mapper = new DataMapper({
        client: new DynamoDB({region: 'us-west-2'}), // the SDK client used to execute operations
        tableNamePrefix: prefix // optionally, you can provide a table prefix to keep your dev and prod tables separate
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to avoid using the `@table` annotation then you can implement your own custom property getter as shown on the [DataMapper documentation](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/tree/master/packages/dynamodb-data-mapper) (second code block in `Getting Started` as of this writing).

Note that the example (using `this.id`) is a bit misleading: In the put/update/delete case (where you will have generally constructed a record object to give to DataMapper) you will have been able to set `this.id` or whatever other fields you're using to compute the table name. But in the query/scan case, where DataMapper uses your supplied constructor to build result objects, you will not have had this opportunity. In the given example, `this.id` would be undefined in a scan or query. You'll need to make sure your `DynamoDbTable` getter works as intended in this case.

Note you can still use the attribute annotations in this case -- they don't conflict since they build separate properties on the underlying class constructor.